# brisk menu keyboard shortcut assignment

Tags: shortcut-keys, ubuntu-mate

I am using ubuntu mate 20.04
I want to assign a custom key combination (i.e. Ctrl+Esc) on [brisk menu](https://github.com/solus-project/brisk-menu) which has as default Mod4(winKey).
I've found its [entry in dconf editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk5JO.jpg), but no other shorcut works apart from the default option.

any ideas?

Comment: I suspect you have a space before and after +: try first removing these spaces.

Comment: @vanadium I've tried both combinations and this is not the reason. I've also tried other key combinations and nothing happens, it's as if this setting doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to type: 
`<Control>Escape` as a hot key in dconf-editor.

Answer (score 0):

Run this to set the shortcut to Ctrl+Esc:

```
gsettings set com.solus-project.brisk-menu hot-key '<Control>Escape'
```

Run this to check the current keyboard shortcut:

```
gsettings get com.solus-project.brisk-menu hot-key
```